# jquery datatables check box value

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

i am using IgnitedDatatables wrapper to present a data in a table form. From the example I manage to do a range filtering using a slider from jquery ui, however I would like to do a filtering based on check box value, but i don't have any idea to pass the check box value to the ajax processing page.

Below is the code for the range filter using a slider:

ajax.php:

```
`<?php`
`require_once('Datatables.php');`
$datatables = new Datatables('mysqli');

// MYSQL configuration
$config = array(
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'xxxxx',
'database' => 'mydb',
'hostname' => 'localhost');

$datatables->connect($config);

$datatables

->select('column1,column2,column3,column4')
->from('mytable');   

if(isset($_POST['min_length']) && $_POST['min_length'] != '')
$datatables->where('column1 >=', $_POST['min_length']);

if(isset($_POST['max_length']) && $_POST['max_length'] != '')
$datatables->where('column1 <=', $_POST['max_length']);

echo $datatables->generate();
?>
```

example.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function()
{
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable
({
"oLanguage" :{ "sSearch" : "Search Global:"
 },
  'bServerSide'    : true,
  'sAjaxSource'    : 'ajax.php',
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
    {
      aoData.push( { "name": "min_length", "value": $( "#min_length" ).val() },
                   { "name": "max_length", "value": $( "#max_length" ).val() },
   );
      $.ajax
        ({
          'dataType': 'json',
          'type'    : 'POST',
          'url'     : sSource,
          'data'    : aoData,
          'success' : fnCallback
        }); 
    },
});

//Slider Range for pVal
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    step: 0.1,
    range: true,
    min: -8,
    max: 8,
    values: [ -8, 8 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#min_length" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
    $( "#max_length" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        oTable.fnDraw();
    }   
});
$( "#min_length" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
$( "#max_length" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ));

</script>
<body id="dt_example">
</head>
<div id="container">
<h1>RRL DGE DB - Advanced Browsing</h1>

<table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="slider">
<div class="demo1">
<div class="demo" style='width:250px;'>
<p>
<tr>
<td><label for="amount">Min:</label><input type="text" id="min_length" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold" disabled=disabled/><br></td>

<td><label for="amount">Max:</label><input type="text" id="max_length" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" disabled=disabled/></td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td width="200">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<div id="slider-range"></div></td>
</div>
</tr>
</p>

</div><!-- End demo -->
</table>

<BR>
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="10%">column1</th>
    <th width="55%">column2</th>
    <th width="10%">column3</th>
    <th width="10%">column4</th>
    <th width="15%">column5</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>loading...</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

</table>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The question is how can I do the same range filtering using checkbox instead of slider? What I need is to send either 0 or 1 value to the ajax.php so that I allow user to select column with 0 or more than 1 results. I am very new php/jquery ui. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add a checkbox with id mycheckbox and add additional parameter in the fnServerData - something like this:

```
'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
  {
     aoData.push( { "name": "min_length", "value": $( "#min_length" ).val() },
                  { "name": "max_length", "value": $( "#max_length" ).val() },
                  { "name": "USEALL", "value": $( "#mycheckbox" ).val() },
  );
```

I think that on the php page you will be able to read new parameter USEALL with value of checkbox.

Jovan